# Use async middleware in Express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a lot of router middlewares in my express app as shown below

```
const router = Express.Router();
router.use(mw1);
router.use(mw2);
router.use(mw3);
router.use(mw4);
router.use(mw5);
```

One of the middleware `mw3` has to make an API call which is an async action, and it set some cookies, which are to be used in `mw5`. So basically `mw3` should resolve, then only `mw5` should be called.

But, when I use an `async` function in `mw3`, express does not wait for the promise to be resolved, before initializing `mw4` and `mw5`

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: How are you calling `next()` in your middlewares? That's what controls when the next middle is called.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what's happening inside of `mw3`

Comment: You have to show us the async middleware code.  Only then an we advise.  In general, you only call `next()` when your async code has finished and that controls the execution flow.  Once you'v'e registered your middelware in a specific order, that's the order they will be called.  You don't get to change that.  You can set something in the request object that mw4 checks and then skips what it would normally do and calls `next()`, thus going onto mw5.